# CPLEX: How to get feasible solutions after abortion of optimization?

Tags: optimization, cplex, ilog

I have a very long lasting optimization process (>100h) and I cannot wait until the end of that process. Nevertheless, I want to get the so far generated solutions (i.e. exact decision variables) of CPLEX. I am using the CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.6. Is this possible and if so, how?

Greetings!

Edit: I'm using OPL inside CPLEX Opt. Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a time limit

```
execute timeTermination {
    cplex.tilim = 3600; // maximum Runtime = 1h  
  }
```

OR you can use gap limit:

```
execute gapTermination {
    cplex.epgap = 0.05; // result at gap of 5%  
  }
```

for the optimization process to stop and output the results.

I added one of those limits on the top of my optimization program (OPL) in CPLEX.

Answer (score 0):

This function is only available in Decition Optimization Center. You can stop optimization process and get generated solutions.

Comment: This should be a comment